# xamarin game development concepts

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin.ios

as showing from title how can I develop a simple 2D Game using xamarin and can I design one game for all platform Ios android and windows phone 
or I should make three different games.

If I should make there Is there any way to copy some code from other ones and alter them.

and is there any book I can read about designing games and I don't want to use another language because c# is my language and I am not looking for learn new programming language such as Udemy...etc

this is my first question I know it is not organized and clear but I hope it won't be the last question and remain the worse question I ever made
thanks in advance.

Comment: This is much too broad to be meaningfully answered here.  Xamarin has excellent docs and walkthroughs, I suggest you take the time to read them.

Comment: could you suggest any PDFs other than xamrain documentation they does have an excellent documentation but it is only availble online and designed to be in chapters some time I want to read from a hard copy or from phone I don't always have net connection

Comment: Every Xamarin doc page is downloadable as PDF.

Comment: really I didn't notice that (PDF for offline use:) last question can download the entire web PDFs or only one by one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as for documentation
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/game_development/

they have PDFs and Videos that could help you

as for is it three games as I understand Yes but that depend on your programming skills if you are expert you can make classes and libraries and only create the interfaces for every platform.